# Maintain page state when using browser back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

[Click to access my wordpress site](https://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/)

Then, click on one of the the baseball graphic toward the top of the page and you'll see the list of baseball teams I'm generating using jQuery:

```html
<li class="">
  <a href="#baseball">
    <img src="http://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2015/09/tab-image2/846523235/844979726.jpg" class=" crb_home_tab_icon" width="156" height="146"> </a>
</li>
```

- Click on one of the links in any of the lists (i.e. Philadelphia Phillies).
- Browse back to the homepage from the Philadelphia Phillies page
- Notice my baseball team list dispappears and the list is set back to the default football teams list.
- I need the baseball list to display when I browse back to home. Preferably with the Philadelphia Phillies link highlighted.

I'm using the jquery.history.js but not working. Any guidance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the back button, it currently loads the URL with a hash for the appropriate menu click.  Because of this, we can use it to emulate a click.

Here is a simplified way to load your content on click of back button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    if(hash == 'baseball' || 
       hash == 'basketball' ||
       hash == 'hockey' ||
       hash == 'artists' ||
       hash == 'events'
    ) {
       $('#menu-' + hash).click();
    }

});
```

Edit:  Something in your code is removing the # when clicking on the sports ball links on the homepage.

To add them back, try this JS:

```
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function() {
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Jacob -thank you for your help. I'm sure I'm missing something but there is a # in the url (from the example above):

Comment: <li class="">
  <a href="#baseball">
    <img src="http://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2015/09/tab-image2/846523235/844979726.jpg" class=" crb_home_tab_icon" width="156" height="146"> </a>
</li>

Comment: @phillystyle123 Yes, actually! That is the first step.  The code I posted should work then.

Comment: In the header and footer. Not working yet. Any ideas? 
Currently I've got it just above </head>

I'm clicking on the baseball graphic, clicking on a baseball team,  the browser back button and the baseball list is replaced with the default football team list. 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    if(hash == 'baseball' || 
       hash == 'basketball' ||
       hash == 'hockey' ||
       hash == 'artists' ||
       hash == 'events'
    ) {
        $('#' + hash).click();
    }

});
</script>

Comment: @phillystyle123 see my edit.  I misread your code.  I changed the jQuery to target the A based on the href.  It would be better to use something different to target them.  One way would be to add an ID to each one, so the links look like this.  `<a href="#baseball" id="menu-baseball">`.  I tested and what I posted seems to work.

Comment: thanks for the help @Jacob Raccuia. Not working yet though. Check out the source code <a href="https://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/">here</a>. 

tabs:
<code><li >
     <a href="#baseball" id="menu-baseball">
      <img src="https://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2015/09/tab-image2/846523235/844979726.jpg" width="156" height="146" class=" crb_home_tab_icon" />     </a>
    </li></code>

Comment: in the footer:

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    if(hash == 'baseball' || 
       hash == 'basketball' ||
       hash == 'hockey' ||
       hash == 'artists' ||
       hash == 'events'
    ) {
       $('a[href=#' + hash + ']').click();
    }

});
</script>
</body>

Comment: @phillystyle123 I updated the JS to reflect the HTML change.  Let me kno!

Comment: Still no luck. Can you take a look at the code? I've moved your code to the header just above the </head> tag and added a link to a jquery history file - which makes no difference either way. <a href="https://luxuryvipsuites.com">click to access site</a>

Comment: @phillystyle123 did you make other changes? the # is no longer being appended to the URL

Comment: I haven't made any other changes. There was never a # appended to the url (except when you mouseover the sports icon image).

Comment: @phillystyle123 that is not true! Your first comment states that there was one there.  Perhaps history.js was working?  You need to add the # to get this solution to work.  Please see my edit for a (less ideal) solution.

Comment: The hashtag is not (and has never been) displayed in the address field. It is indeed in the code so when you mouseover/click the icon, you'll see it in the status bar in the lower left corner of your browser screen (in firefox). The history.js script is already there. I'll try your back js -thanks.